# R legend pch mix of character and numeric

Tags: r

Is it possible to use a mix of character and number as plotting symbols in R legend?

```
plot(x=c(2,4,8),y=c(5,4,2),pch=16)
points(x=c(3,5),y=c(2,4),pch="+")
legend(7,4.5,pch=c("+",16),legend=c("A","B")) #This is the problem
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My first thought is to plot the legend twice, once to print the character symbols and once to print the numeric ones:

```
plot(x=c(2,4,8),y=c(5,4,2),pch=16)
points(x=c(3,5),y=c(2,4),pch="+")
legend(7,4.5,pch=c(NA,16),legend=c("A","B")) # NA means don't plot pt. character 
legend(7,4.5,pch=c("+",NA),legend=c("A","B"))
```

**NOTE:** Oddly, this works in R's native graphical device (on Windows) and in `pdf()`, but not in `bmp()` or `png()` devices ...

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Yes This was actually my current solution. But the problem here is that I use smartlegend() from gplots to plot the legends so I dont have to specify coordinates just indicate top/bottom, left or right. In that case, if I plot two legends, they overplot. But thanks :-)

Comment: @Roy First of all, legend() also takes coordinates as "bottomleft", "bottomright", ... No need to use smartlegend() for that. Second, this solution also overplots two legends. That's what you need to do, as `c("+",16)` is always converted to a character vector before it's passed to the `legend()` function.

Comment: If overplotting is an issue: `legend(7,4.5,pch=c(NA,16),legend=c("A","B")); legend(7,4.5,pch=c("+",NA),legend=c(" "," "), bty="n")` you can just blank all the elements that would overplot in the second call to `legend`.

Answer (score 12):

Use the numerical equivalent of the "+" character:

```
plot(x=c(2,4,8),y=c(5,4,2),pch=16)
points(x=c(3,5),y=c(2,4),pch="+")
legend(7,4.5,pch=c(43,16),legend=c("A","B"))
```

Comment: For anyone interested, the numerical equivalent of the alphabet starts at `pch=65` for A.

Comment: For completeness...
The documentation (`?points`  or  [https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/points.html] ) states:
‘32:127’: ASCII characters.

For a list of these, see e.g.
[https://www.hesa.ac.uk/component/content/article?id=1531]

Comment: Rather than manually looking up the ASCII code and then hardcoding it, suggest: `legend(7,4.5,pch=c(charToRaw("+"),16),legend=c("A","B"))`

Answer (score 10):

There are actually numerical equivalents for all symbols!

[image]

<sup>Source: [Dave Roberts](https://davidrroberts.wordpress.com/2015/06/02/r-pch-symbol-library-plot/)</sup>

The pch code is the **[concatenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation) of the Y and X coordinates** of the above plot.

- For example, the `+` symbol is in row (Y) 4 and column (X) 3, and therefore can be drawn using pch = 43.

Example:

```
plot(x=c(2,4,8),y=c(5,4,2),pch=16)
points(x=c(3,5),y=c(2,4),pch="+")
legend(7,4.5,pch=c(43,16),legend=c("A","B"))
```

Answer (score 3):

I bumped to this issue several time, so I wrote a tiny function below. You can use to specify the pch value, e.g.

```
pch=c(15:17,s2n("|"))
```

[String to Numeric](https://github.com/kklot/R-Utils/blob/master/s2n.R)

Answer (score 0):

As [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18090036/4581200) in previous answers,  you can simply add the [numerical equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43073911/4581200) of the numeric and character symbols you want to plot.

However, just a related aside: if you want to plot larger numbers (e.g., > 100) or strings (e.g., 'ABC') as symbols, you need to use a totally different approach based on using `text()`.

```
`Plot(x,y,dat,type='n') ; text(x,y,labels = c(100,'ABC')
```

Creating a legend in this case is more complicated, and the best approach I've ever come up with is to **stack legends on top of each other and using the `legend` argument for both the `pch` symbol and the description**:

```
pchs <- c(100,'ABC','540',sum(13+200),'SO77')

plot(1:5,1:5,type='n',xlim=c(1,5.1))
  text(1:5,1:5,labels = pchs)
  legend(3.5,3,legend = pchs,bty='n',title = '')
  legend(3.5,3,legend = paste(strrep(' ',12),'ID#',pchs),bty='n',title='Legend')
  rect(xleft = 3.7, ybottom = 1.5, xright = 5.1, ytop = 3)
```

- This uses [`strrep`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strrep.html) to concatenate spaces in order to shift the text over from the "symbols", and it uses [`rect`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/rect.html) to retroactively fit a box around the printed legend text.

[image]